# Show that the following Inequalities holds

Tags: inequality

I came across this inequalities that requires the conclusion of a prove. Please does this Inequalities hold? And how can I prove it?

> Given a finite increasing sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$.

1. $$ x_1^2 k_1 + (x_2^2 - x_1^2) k_2 +\dots +(x_n^2 - x_{n-1}^2)k_n \geq \big (x_1 k_1 + (x_2 -x_1)k_2)+\dots+(x_n - x_{n-1})k_n \big)^2 $$ Where $0\leq k_i \leq k$ and $k_n, k_1 >0$
2. $$k \left( \sum_i k_i {x_i}^2 + 2\sum_{i<j}k_j x_i x_j \right) \ge \left( 
   \sum_i k_i x_i \right)^2 $$

I am thinking of applying the Holder's inequality. But I don't really know how to approach this. Any help or hint is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $0\leq k_i \leq 1$? Otherwise it is wrong already for $n=1$.

Comment: @MartinR Oh thanks for the observation

Comment: @MartinR I edited the question. please how about the second inequality, does it hold?. thanks

Comment: Where do the inequalities come from? Why do you think they might be true? How is the second inequality related to the first one?

Comment: The second inequality is from a research paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-017-9883-x On the Circle Covering theorem by A.W Goodman. proof of Lemma 4.1. The writer concluded that it holds since $k \ge k_i$

Comment: Expanding the RHS gives $ \sum_i k_i^2 {x_i}^2 + 2\sum_{i<j}k_i k_j x_i x_j $, and that is $\le$ the LHS.

Comment: What is the RHS of the first expression? The left and right parentheses don't seem to match up. Is it supposed to be $\left(x_1k_1+(x_2−x_1)k_2+⋯+(x_n−x_{n−1})k_n\right)^2$? Do we have $k_i \leq 1$ (you haven't edited your question to reflect that)?

Comment: I agree with Martin that we require  $ 0 \leq k_i \leq 1$. OP claims to have edited this in, but all that I see is $ 0 \leq k_i \leq k$, with no clarification of what $k$ is equal to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second inequality is obviously true, and precisely because $ k \geq k_i$ as stated in the paper (from OP's comment).

$$k \left( \sum_i k_i {x_i}^2 + 2\sum_{i<j}k_j x_i x_j \right) =  \sum k k_i x_i^2  + 2 \sum_{i<j} k k_j x_i x_j \geq  \sum k_i^2 x_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i<j } k_i k_j x_i x_j          = \left( 
\sum_i k_i x_i \right)^2. $$

Comment: Yeah that's true. thanks  for more clarity